# printed mysql query giving two different results with and without spaces

Tags: php

I have two different queries and I just try to print the part of my query as bellow,

```
$dateSql="DATE(DATE_SUB(ec.membership_expires,INTERVAL 1 WEEK))";
echo "1 : (DATE(ec.last_reminder) < $dateSql and NOW() >= $dateSql)";
echo "2 : (DATE(ec.last_reminder)<$dateSql and NOW()>=$dateSql)";
```

and I will get two different results :

> 1 : (DATE(ec.last_reminder) <
>   DATE(DATE_SUB(ec.membership_expires,INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) and NOW() >=
>   DATE(DATE_SUB(ec.membership_expires,INTERVAL 1 WEEK)))
>
> 2 : (DATE(ec.last_reminder)=DATE(DATE_SUB(ec.membership_expires,INTERVAL 1
>   WEEK)))

Can someone explain why it happens?

Comment: They are not mysql queries, but a php code. If you want to ask a question about mysql - provide the pure mysql queries that contain nothing but mysql queries.

Comment: ok im sorry, i will add php tag as well

Comment: And remove tag `mysql` probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you're looking the result in a browser, which treats

```
<DATE(DATE_SUB(ec.membership_expires,INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) and NOW()>
```

as a tag and just skips it since it's invalid.

What you need to do - is just to see source of the page, run it in a terminal or wrap the whole output in `htmlspecialchars()`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NnEL6/

Answer (score 2):

Guess time:

You're viewing the result **in a browser** which interprets **HTML**. `<FOO` means something in HTML, `< FOO` doesn't...

Comment: yes you are correct, i have check with http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and its giving me two results "Display as text" and "Display as HTML". when I choose HTML it is giving my current result